# How to delete the folder contents using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

Suppose I have an Excel sheet, which has the some numbers say:

- 77787
- 45877
- 78985 so on...

*Now I have an directory called as "D://Filehosting" in windows 7 machine. under that directory I have some 500 folders, each of them having 120 files in it. Now I want to delete the contents of each folder which which are 2 months older from the current date. Now the folders are arranged something like below:*

- D://Filehosting/Document77787
- D://Filehosting/Document45877 .. so on

***Script should take the numbers as mentioned above, and accordingly    find the right directory and accordingly delete the contents.Must    check if the if the folder exists or not before content deletion    approach.***

Can it be done using Ruby?

Comment: What you are asking it quite trivial. Have you Googled? What have you tried. I would convert the Excel sheet to a CSV file if it only has numbers, use a gem like FasterCSV and then iterate over the results checking if the folder exists before content deletion.

Comment: Maybe you need `File#mtime`, `FileUtils#rm`, `Dir#glob`

Comment: @Anand my question is how to find the directories, from where i have to delete the contents. I can read the numbers from the Excel itself I know that1

Comment: @CodeLover the later part of my comment says iterate over the results checking the necessary stuff. zed_0xff has given an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  def del_dir id
    Dir["D:/Filehosting/Document#{id}/*"].each do |fname|
      next unless File.file?(fname)                # skip accident dirs
      if Time.now-File.mtime(fname) > 2*30*24*3600 # nearly 2 months
        puts "[!] will delete #{fname}, mtime=#{File.mtime(fname)}"
        # File.unlink(fname)                       # uncomment this to actually delete
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: How would you construct the `fname`? what I have is only `the Request number` and the base directory `Filehosting`. then how would I make `Document77787` so on.. on the fly?

Comment: `#` is oncatenation operator in Ruby?

Comment: no, it's an insertion of result of some ruby operations into strings